# VB Net - SQL - Compare Values of textbox and SQL Value

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

here's my code:

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    Try
        myCmd = myConn.CreateCommand
        myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        myCmd.CommandText = ("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = '" + txtboxUser.Text + "'")
        myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        myReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        While myReader.Read
            UserVerifier = myReader.GetString(0).ToString()
            PassVerifier = myReader.GetString(1).ToString()
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrorDB()
    End Try
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(UserVerifier) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Username does not exist", "Login Failed.")
        txtboxUser.Clear()
        txtboxPassword.Clear()
        txtboxUser.Select()
    Else
        If txtboxPassword.Text = PassVerifier Then
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome" + txtboxUser.Text + "!", "Login Success!")
            Me.Hide()
            Form1.Show()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Password", "Login Failed.")
            txtboxPassword.Clear()
            txtboxPassword.Select()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

and it seems that this line of code does not seem to work, it always does not match:

```
If txtboxPassword.Text = PassVerifier Then
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome" + txtboxUser.Text + "!", "Login Success!")
            Me.Hide()
            Form1.Show()
        Else
```

I have tried to do several solutions that I have researched and none of them seems to work. Maybe there's something missing in my code? And can someone please explain to me why "PassVerifier = myReader.GetString(1).ToString()" doesn't return a string datatype? what does it get then? How can I convert it so it can be the same as txtboxPassword.Text? I'm really confused, please help. Thank you so much.

Edit: Even though txtboxPassword.Text and PassVerifier has the same result, why can't the If statement,"If txtboxPassword.Text = PassVerifier Then", work? am I lacking something on getting the data or converting it? it always passes that and it always result on the Else statement.

Comment: Given that, as the name suggests, `GetString` returns a `String`, what's the point of calling `ToString` on the result? It doesn't hurt but it shows that you're not actually thinking about your data types, which will always lead to issues somewhere at some time. Also, if you want to concatenate `Strings`, use the concatenation operator (`&`) and not the addition operator (`+`). They do the same thing in many cases but not all. The former always does the right thing so just always use it and you can't go wrong.

Comment: As for the issue, debug your code. You should have done that before posting here. If the two values always match on that line then the two values are always the same. What do you want us to do about that? It's up to you to debug your code and see where the data is coming from and exactly where and how your code behaves differently to your expectations. At the very least, you should be able to tell us where and how that is. If the data that comes from your database is not what you expect then either your database is wrong or your query is wrong.

Comment: Finally, you should learn how to use parameters with ADO.NET as the way you're building your query has all sorts of issues, not least of which is security.

Comment: question edited!

Comment: @jmcilhinney tbh I'm just doing on how our professor taught us to do :/ Apologies for the lots of errors!

Comment: Plenty of people are taught badly, so it's up to you whether you want to make changes to improve your code when suggested. Some teachers don't like that and will mark it down, so that's up to you. Regardless, you still need to debug your code.

Comment: will do and thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: is this a windows app or web app?

Comment: @Jeremy windows app sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a good idea to separate you user interface code from you database access code. The UI code deals with `MessageBox` and controls and such. The database code doesn't show `MesageBox`es or even know about controls. I put the Try/Catch in the UI code so you can communicate any errors to the user.

Your database objects should be declared in the method where they are used so they can be properly closed and disposed. Using blocks declare and dispose these objects. Pass the connection string to the constructor of the connection and the command text and connection to the constructor of the command.

**Always** use parameters to avoid sql injection and other reasons. I had to guess at the datatype and field size. Check your database for the correct values.

Since you only need the count, there is no reason to pull down the entire record. Since we are only retrieving a single value you can use `.ExecuteScalar`.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"

Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    If txtboxUser.Text = "" OrElse txtboxPassword.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("please fill all boxes")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim RetVal As Boolean
    Try
        RetVal = ValidateLogin(txtboxUser.Text, txtboxPassword.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    If RetVal Then
        MessageBox.Show("Welcome" + txtboxUser.Text + "!", "Login Success!")
        Me.Hide()
        Form1.Show()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Login Failed.")
    End If
End Sub

Private Function ValidateLogin(User As String, Password As String) As Boolean
    Dim RetVal As Boolean
    Dim ReturnedCount As Integer
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("Select Count(*) From [login] WHERE [username] = @Username AND [password] = @Password;", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = User
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = Password
        cn.Open()
        ReturnedCount = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
    End Using 'closes the connection, disposes the connection and command
    If ReturnedCount = 1 Then 'there is a matching record
        RetVal = True
    End If
    Return RetVal
End Function
```

Of course, in a real application you would **NEVER** store passwords as plain text.

Comment: I know this is 3 days late but, Thanks for the explanation! Everything works fine now and everything's much more clear to me. Thank you so much and Godbless :)))

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you don't show where you setup the conneciton, and the "cmd" variable.

These should not be left to chance.

And you don't show in your code where you check the password.

I'll assume you done a imports system.data.SqlClient at the top of the module.

And I'll assume you used + set a connection string in the project "settings".

So, our code will:

```
Check for user - if none tell user
Check for password - if none tell user

Check if user name exists - if not - tell user
Check if pasword match - if not - tell user.
```

The code thus will look like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If txtBoxUser.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a user name", "No user name")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If txtboxPassword.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a password", "No password")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM login "
    Dim MyTable As New DataTable

    Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("", New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TESTdb))

        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()

        cmdSQL.CommandText = strSQL & " WHERE username = @User"
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@User", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtBoxUser.Text

        MyTable.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)

        If MyTable.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("User name does not exist", "Logon Failed")
        Else
            ' name was ok - try name + password
            cmdSQL.CommandText = strSQL & " WHERE userName = @User AND Password = @Pass"
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Pass", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtboxPassword.Text
            MyTable.Clear()
            MyTable.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            If MyTable.Rows.Count = 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Password incorrect", "Password fail")
            End If
        End If

        ' get here without rows, then clear passwords info, or we are OK!!!
        If MyTable.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            txtBoxUser.Clear()
            txtboxPassword.Clear()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome " & txtBoxUser.Text & "!", "Login Success!")
        End If

    End Using

End Sub
```

Now we should move this to a separate "function" from the button sub, and have this routine return true or false based on success or fail, but I'll leave that part to you (have to leave you something to do here!).

Comment: You are showing message boxes with an open connection. I think the connection should be local to the method where it is used. Why would you inform a potential hacker exactly what part of the login is wrong? A login failed is enough. Why hit the database twice? Why pull down the entire record when all you need is Count?